# SQL query to select one row from each group with preference

Tags: sql

For an example suppose I have a table with two columns `X` and `Y`. Now I want to `select` from this table some rows with the following rules:

1. Define a "group" to be a group of rows that have same value of the column `Y`.
2. From a group, only one row is chosen.
3. In a group, if one of the rows has `X=a` where a is predefined, then that row is chosen from that group.
4. In a group, if no row has `X=a`, then any row can be chosen.

What are my options to do this in a single SQL query?

Comment: *`From a group, only one row is chosen.`* Which x value should be chosen for each y group??

Comment: @MahmoudGamal : any row. Just rule 3 should be followed. updated the question.

Comment: What if there are more than one rows with X=a ?

Comment: There won't be. And this goes for all possible values of X. In a group, there will be only one row with any value of X. Basically X and Y together can be called a `key`.

@MahmoudGamal : Sqlite3, if that's what you want to know

Comment: Which RDBMS are you working with? SQL-Server, MySQL, Oracle, Postgres, DB2, SQLite, ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  t1.Y,
  COALESCE(a2.x, a1.x) 'x'
FROM Tablename t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT Y, MIN(x) x
    FROM Tablename
    GROUP BY Y
) a1 ON t1.Y = a1.Y
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT Y, MIN(x) x
    FROM Tablename
    WHERE x = 'a'
    GROUP BY Y
) a2 ON t1.Y = a2.Y;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/24577/4)

Comment: I think it should be coelsce(a2.x, a1.x).

Comment: @prongs Update, you may be need to use `IFNULL` instead for SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP SCHEMA tmp CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA tmp ;
SET search_path=tmp;

CREATE TABLE yx
        ( Y INTEGER NOT NULL
        , x CHAR NOT NULL
        , PRIMARY KEY (y,x)
        );
INSERT INTO yx (y,x) VALUES
 (10,'b') ,(10,'d') ,(10,'e' )  -- y==10 does not have an 'a'
,(20,'b') ,(20,'a') ,(20,'d')   -- y==20 does have an 'a'
        ;

        --
        -- using a CTE
        --
WITH    this AS (
        SELECT y,x
        , row_number() OVER (PARTITION by y ORDER BY (x='a') DESC, x ASC) AS rnk
        FROM yx
        )
SELECT this.y,this.x 
FROM this
WHERE this.rnk = 1
        ;

        --
        -- with a subselect instead of a CTE
        --
SELECT this.y,this.x 
FROM (
        SELECT y,x
        , row_number() OVER (PARTITION by y ORDER BY (x='a') DESC, x ASC) AS rnk
        FROM yx
        ) this
WHERE this.rnk = 1
        ;
```